# Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm trying so create using Laravel eloquent relationship but I'm getting this error

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

**This is what I'm trying to do in my controller**

```
$data = $request->all();

    $company = Company::create([
      'name' => $data['name'],
      'description' => $data['description'],
    ]);

    $company->members->create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'status' => $data['status'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
```

**This is my Company Model**

```
class Company extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [  'name', 'description'];

public function members(){
  $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function reports(){
  $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
}
```

This is my User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'company_id','status',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function company(){
  $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

**And this is the error I'm getting**

```
(1/1) LogicException
Relationship method must return an object of type 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
in HasAttributes.php (line 403)
at Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('members')
in HasAttributes.php (line 386)
at Model->getRelationValue('members')
in HasAttributes.php (line 316)
at Model->getAttribute('members')
in Model.php (line 1262)
at Model->__get('members')
in AdminController.php (line 48)
at AdminController->addCompany(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminController), 'addCompany'), array(object(Request)))
in Controller.php (line 55)
at Controller->callAction('addCompany', array(object(Request)))
in ControllerDispatcher.php (line 44 )
```

How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have forgotten to return the relation like so :

```
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}

public function members(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}

public function reports(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
```

Comment: hahaha... i can't believe i forgot that.. i almost cried because of this error.. Thanks very much

Comment: Also correct here : 
`$company->members->create([...])` to `$company->members()->create([])`